# Widget view destroyed after installation of new app

Tags: android, widget

I am developing a widget.It is a stackview widget.I just get images from server and load it,It is working fine.But After the installation of new app, it stop working. i did not get any error, just i lost it's view part which i load dynamically.

Comment: your question is too obscure. please provide some more details.

Comment: I have a stackview widget which working fine.but after installation of new app,it is lost it's view only loading icon is there.